# php walking through an array is missing one key ( that seems to be present )

Tags: php, arrays

Good afternoon
I have an array I need to walk through in order to find dates set in the array.
if the date is found, the output needs to be a different bgcolor than if not.
so far so good. I walk through the array via a sorted second array

```
function huisjes_tabel($soorten, $huisjes, $days, $maand, $jaar){
$col_buffer = "";
$dag = $days;
$buffer = "<table border=1><tr>";
    foreach ($soorten as $soort){ 
        $col_buffer .= "<td><table border=0 width=100%>";
        $color = rand("100000","999999");
        $soort = trim($soort);
        if(isset($huisjes[$soort] )){
        echo $soort."<br />";
            for($i =1; $i <= $days; $i++){
                if(strlen($i) == 1){$dag ="0".$i;} else {$dag = $i;}
                if(in_array($jaar.$maand.$dag, $huisjes[$soort])){
                    $col_buffer .= "<tr><td align=center bgcolor=#".$color."><a href=factuurlijst.php?plaats=".$soort."&dag=".$jaar.$maand.$dag.">".$dag."</a></td></tr>";
                } else {
                    $col_buffer .= "<tr><td align=center bgcolor=#f1f1f1>".$dag."</td></tr>";               
                }
            }
        } 
        $col_buffer .= "</table></td>";
    }
    $buffer .=  $col_buffer."</tr></table>";
    return $col_buffer;
}


Array // types
(
 [0] => chalet 13
 [1] => chalet 14
 [2] => chalet 15
 [3] => chalet 16
 [4] => bungalow 1
 [5] => bungalow 2
)

Array // huisjes
(
    [chalet 16] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20140501
            [1] => 20140502
            [2] => 20140503
            [3] => 20140504
            [4] => 20140505
            [5] => 20140506
            [6] => 20140507
            [7] => 20140508
            [8] => 20140509
            [9] => 20140510
            [10] => 20140511
            [11] => 20140512
        )

    [chalet 13] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20140517
            [1] => 20140518
            [2] => 20140523
            [3] => 20140524
            [4] => 20140525
            [5] => 20140529
            [6] => 20140530
            [7] => 20140531
        )

    [chalet 14] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20140501
            [1] => 20140502
            [2] => 20140503
            [3] => 20140517
            [4] => 20140518
            [5] => 20140523
            [6] => 20140524
            [7] => 20140525
            [8] => 20140530
            [9] => 20140531
        )

    [chalet 15] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20140501
            [1] => 20140502
            [2] => 20140503
            [3] => 20140504
            [4] => 20140505
            [5] => 20140506
            [6] => 20140507
            [7] => 20140508
            [8] => 20140509
            [9] => 20140510
            [10] => 20140511
            [11] => 20140512
            [12] => 20140523
            [13] => 20140524
            [14] => 20140525
            [15] => 20140530
            [16] => 20140531
        )

    [bungalow 2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20140517
            [1] => 20140518
            [2] => 20140519
            [3] => 20140520
            [4] => 20140521
            [5] => 20140522
            [6] => 20140528
            [7] => 20140529
            [8] => 20140530
            [9] => 20140531
        )

    [bungalow 1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20140522
            [1] => 20140523
            [2] => 20140524
            [3] => 20140525
            [4] => 20140526
            [5] => 20140527
            [6] => 20140528
            [7] => 20140529
            [8] => 20140530
            [9] => 20140531
        )

)
```

The problem I am facing is the following:
When walking through the types array, I am not getting a equal match on "chalet 13".
I have been debugging big time and lost for the moment.

Hope anyone of you can see the obvious and point it out to me
All help is welcome and thanks in advance

```
array
  0 => string 'chalet 13' (length=9)
  1 => string 'chalet 14' (length=9)
  2 => string 'chalet 15' (length=9)
  3 => string 'chalet 16' (length=9)
  4 => string 'bungalow 1' (length=10)
  5 => string 'bungalow 2' (length=10)

'chalet 13' => 
    array
      0 => int 20140517
      1 => int 20140518
      2 => int 20140523
      3 => int 20140524
      4 => int 20140525
      5 => int 20140529
      6 => int 20140530
      7 => int 20140531
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no extra spaces somewhere in the key?

Comment: Yes I am sure about that, see below the var_dump of both arrays.

Comment: Is that "if(in_array())" bit the code which does not see "chalet 13"?

Comment: it is more the part if(isset($huisjes[$type])) that seems to be causing the trouble

Comment: What is the value(s) of `$jaar.$maand.$dag`?

Comment: @BrettSantore:  You can see that as the values (Netherlandsese for year, month, day).

Comment: What code precedes the *foreach* loop?  Maybe the internal pointer of where in the array is next is not at the beginning.

Comment: there is no "real" code before, both arrays are passed to the function ( where the code snap comes form ) 
when I echo $type right after if(isset($huisjes[$type])) chalet13 is already missing. var_dumps are done just before foreach ($types as $type)

Comment: @BrettSantore these are indeed the date values for year, month and day. for all other types this works like expected, just not for chalet 13

Comment: Right, but where are those coming from … and what does an 'equal match' mean?

Comment: updated my code to current, pasted whole function now.
with the equal match I mean, I am not getting a match between the type (soort) and the index in the huisjes array

Comment: Have you already tried my code? Because I see that you add the extra 0 to $dag, but not to $maand...

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting this before the foreach loop:

```
reset ($types);
foreach($types as $type){ ...
```

This sets the [internal array pointer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) to the beginning.

Comment: have tried that, but the value that is dropping is not the first or last in the "list" of arrays. is not solving my issue for now :-(

Comment: @FonsSeesink:  Well, at least the problem is not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that if you would like to concatenate a integer like "05", then it strips the 0. So is is looking for a key like 2014522 instead of 20140522

This will solve your problem:

```
foreach ($types as $type){ 
    if(isset($huisjes[$type] )){
        $find = date("Ymd", mktime(0, 0, 0, $maand, $dag, $jaar));
        if(in_array($find, $huisjes[$type])){
            $buffer = "<tr><td bgcolor=#".$color.">".$jaar.$maand.$dag."</td></tr>";
        } else {
            $buffer = "<tr><td bgcolor=#f1f1f1>".$jaar.$maand.$dag."</td></tr>";        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1.  The loop is constructed such that even if it did not "find" the item, it would still display it, just in a different color.  2. The search key is built with string concatenation, so as long as the variables are strings, it should work.

Comment: 1. Right, but where do you read there's nothing displayed? FonsSeesink only says he is "not getting an equal match". 2. Right again, but I think the variables are integers...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to have wasted your time on this, but many thanks for the great ideas pushing me to the solution!
Ends up that the database had the value 'chalet 13' where the reservations where holding 'Chalet 13' 
By using strtolower when filling the array, it seems that the $type in the array changed and this leads to different behavior later on in the code.
I now updated the database for this chalet to have the same values everywhere and chalet 13 is showing nice and clean now in the overview.